# Анимация маршрута в Яндекс API

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В песочнице есть пример анимированной линии https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polyline_animation
Можно ли как то использовать не Polyline а маршрут(**multiroute**) как в этом примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options
(если строить линией, то  точек больше 200 вручную писать приходится, еще и с масштабированием при длинном пути получается нужно разрывать линии на границе карты и прыгать **pan to**..

**Вопрос:** Можно ли сделать анимированный маршрут с помощью **multiroute**?
при этом если маршрут уходит дальше чем видно то карта сама зуммируется как нужно,а еще лучше если карта сама передвигается при "росте" анимированного маршрута ( как в навигаторе например)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решения из коробки у JS API Карт нет, нужно писать самостоятельно.

Собрать маршрут в линию можно с помощью этого кода:

```
// Собираем по линии для каждой нитки маршрута.
    const lineGeoObjects = multiRoute.getRoutes().toArray()
      .map(route => new ymaps.Polyline(routeToLineString(route)));
```

Анимировать её вы можете с помощью этого примера: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polyline_animation

Передвигать карту с помощью panTo и setCenter.

Определить, что координаты не попадают в границы карты или какой-то заданной области можно с помощью этого примера https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/show_visible_objects